Etymology of the term "sigma-finite" measure
As many people on this site know, and could probably recite by heart at any minute, the definition of a $\sigma$-finite measure is as follows:
Let $(X, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ be a measure space. The measure $\mu$ is said to be $\sigma$-finite if there exist $\{E_n\}_{n=1}^{n=\infty} \subseteq \mathcal{F}$ satisfying:
(i) $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n = X$
(ii) $\mu(E_n)$ is finite for all $n$
There is also the definition of a $\sigma$-algebra, namely a collection of subsets of $X$ that (i) contains $X$ (ii) is closed under complements and (iii) is closed under countable unions.

Question: Why is the Greek lowercase letter $\sigma$ used as an adjectival modifier in the above definitions? Does the letter $\sigma$ have some connection with the word "countable"?
(Obviously, I am well aware that the capital $\Sigma$ is very much associated with summations, and these summations are often considered over a countable indexing set (although not always!), so perhaps there is some connection here. But on the other hand, if there is such a strong association with uppercase $\Sigma$ and "countableness", then why don't we call it a $\Sigma$-measure or a $\Sigma$-algebra?)

Historically people used $\sigma$ for things to do with countable unions and $\delta$ to do with countable intersections. See for instance $\sigma$-algebra, $\sigma$-finite, $F_\sigma$, etc.

Trying to close this question as a duplicate is crashing the page for me for some reason... So maybe I'll say manually that this has been asked before here and here. It's on MO rather than MSE, but see also here for a direct historical reference.

Greek letter $\sigma$ corresponds to the German word Summe, which [100 years ago] was used to mean "union".  Similarly, Greek $\delta$ corresponds to the German word Durcschnit, which was used to mean "intersection"

@ChrisGrossack Thank you very much for taking the time to reply. Your comments, and links, are extremely helpful. I apologize for posting a question that already had an answer--I was not aware of the other posts. Thank you again for your help.
